# Firebase via node.js for dummies?

Tags: node.js, firebase, npm

I have a server for my websites. The root folder have a public_html for my main site, then I have folders for my other sites. For example 'site2' in the root folder acts as the public_html for example www.site2.com and so on. The index file `./site2/index.php` === www.site2.com in other words and vice versa.

I have tried logging into my SSH and installing node.js (installed in root folder with folder name 'nodejs' as per [a2 hostings instructions](https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/installable-applications/manual-installations/installing-node-js-on-managed-hosting-accounts)), then both:

`npm install firebase-tools -g`  and without the `-g` in the folder `./site2/firebase/cv` where I want my index.html for my first firebase project, but to avail.

I have also tried to follow the Firebase documentation '[Add Firebase to your JavaScript Projec](https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup)t' but there I don't understand what they mean with the package.json file. I ran `npm init` and got a process prompt to create one. But what values should I input? Where should I out the file? What? Wat?

**Note!** Each time I have removed the folder links that was created in my ./bin folder (`firebase-> ../lib/node_modules/firebase-tools/bin/firebase/` and `npm-> ../nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js`), the `node` file in the same directory, the `./lib` and the `./nodejs` folder and any of the same created in the `./site2/firebase/` folder before installing it in a new way (of those I mentioned that I've tried).

I have also logged in via `firebase login --interactive` (did that early and I'm still logged in if I try again).

No matter what I do, I get errors that the firebase specific variables are not recognized, or that the dependencies (in the header when using `firebase init hosting`) are not found when opening the inspector console in the browser.

**So:** Seeing that I have the folder structure that I have for my sites after installing node.js (with `./nodejs/` as the install for node.js and thus a `./bin` folder with the `npm-> ../nodejs/lib/node_modules/npm/bin/npm-cli.js` folder link and the `node` file in `/bin`, and that I want to use firebase for `./site2/firebase/cv/index.html`:

Can someone give me a step by step? Is there any hope? I liked the way it was when I tested it locally, where I can just have `<script src="app.js"></script>` tag before the end of my body tag and then the dependencies in the head tag, like in the autogenerated file when using the `firebase.init hosting` command.

I don't want to put script tags in my page with credidentials like the snippet I can grab from the Firebase console and I want to host my files myself (but use the firebase database, auth features etc).

Answer (score 0):

In this page you have what you need to do to use Firebase on the web just follow the instruction or watch the Youtube videos, there is more video on the Firebase channel:  https://firebase.google.com/docs/web/setup

And it's meant to be used like this, meaning adding script tags and credentials.

Also Firebase Cli has nothing to do with using the Firebase real time db in your app, it's rather a tool to use if you want to use Firebase hosting, cloud functions etc.

Comment: Oh and if you want to use Node.js with Firebase you would also need to do npm install firebase --save to install Firebase SDK

Comment: How would I have the paths I have if I haven&#39;t?

Comment: I have installed it up and down and all around in every flavor I could find. That&#39;s why I&#39;m asking for it in more detail than explained and fitted to my example of hosting structure (try googling 'hosting' and firebase.. Ha! ). I have tried videos, websites, Stackoverflow answers to the strangest details in the process (like folder links, I still don&#39;t know what they really are, just that they are there and now how to create and remove them)